# HERE Map Tile Labels only using specified language at certain zoom levels?

Tags: here-api

We are using HERE JS API to show a HERE map widget on our site. We need specify a specific language for the map tiles, so we found this API reference that says we can send in a map tile language on creation of the defaultLayers. 
ex: [this doc](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-service-platform.html#h-service-platform__createdefaultlayers), though we did find we had to use "lg" instead of "lang".

We pass in the language on layer creation as follows:

```
var maptypes = platform.createDefaultLayers({
   tileSize: devicePixelRatio > 1 ? 512 : 256,
   ppi: devicePixelRatio > 1 ? 320 : 72,
   lg: "hin"
});
```

It seems to partially work. At farther away zoom levels, I can see the labels are in Hindi. However, sometimes when I zoom in or out, the labels become romanized English characters. Is this expected behavior? Is there any way I can resolve this?

Hindi showing up initially:

[image: Hindi showing up initially]

English showing up in labels when zoomed in by minimal amount:

[image: English showing up in labels]

These are the versions we are using:

```
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-mapevents.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: Are the names specifically need to be in Hindi for the regions which lie outside the India ? Can you please help to clear the requirement.

Comment: It's not as important that the areas outside of India to be in Hindi. However, we are not only going to be supporting this in India / Hindi in the future so ideally we don't want to put in any configuration that won't work for other countries. 

Even in India though, if we zoom in very far towards Hyderabad, it seems like the labels switch from Hindi to English.

Example:
1) https://wego.here.com/?map=12.18097,78.44172,11,satellite vs
2) https://wego.here.com/?map=12.18097,78.44172,13,satellite&x=ep

^ Same coordinate, different zoom, labels turn to English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have already figured out in order to change the language of the map tiles you need to pass the **lg** parameter. It is stated in the [HERE Map Tile API documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-tile/topics/resource-base-maptile.html#resource-base-maptile__includes-query-parameters).

> The MARC three-letter language code for requesting a map tile rendered in a specific language. If the given language is not available, the default language **eng** is used.

So that is why specifying **lg=hin** won't show absolutely all labels in that language.

About **createDefaultLayers** method. So you can call it by passing several arguments or an object. Example:

```
const tileSize = devicePixelRatio > 1 ? 512 : 256;
const ppi = devicePixelRatio > 1 ? 320 : 72;

platform.createDefaultLayers(tileSize, ppi, "hin");
```

or (mind the ES6 object initialiser notation)

```
platform.createDefaultLayers({tileSize, ppi, lg: "hin"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following dependencies

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.css?dp-version=1549984893" />
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-clustering.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.cit.datalens.api.here.com/latest/mapsjs-datalens.js"></script>
```

Comment: Could I have some information on what the ".cit" is for and what the expected differences should be? And what datalens is helping with?